# Why is this an illegal constant expression?

Tags: c, static, expression, constants, storage-class-specifier

I am trying to preserve a variable so I can see its value while debugging optimized code. 
Why is the following an illegal constant expression?

```
   void foo(uint_32 x)
   {
       static uint_32 y = x;
       ...
   }
```

Comment: `x` is a variable, not a constant.

Comment: The initial value of a static variable has to be evaluable at compile time. `x` isn't known until the function is called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your purpose you probably want this:

```
void foo(uint_32 x)
{
    static uint_32 y;
    y = x;
    ...
}
```

What you tried to do is an initialisation. What is done above is an assignment.

---

Maybe for your purpose this would be even more interesting:

```
static uint_32 y;
void foo(uint_32 x)
{
    y = x;
    ...
}
```

Now the variable `y` can easily be accessed by the debugger once the `foo` function is finished.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that the static variable is zero initialized in this case?

Comment: @Pistanic yes, static variables are initialized to zero.

Comment: This code is equivalent to using a non-static variable `y`

Comment: @M.M as far as I understood he wants `y` to persist after `x` has gone out of scope for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 5):

> "*Why is the following an illegal constant expression?*"

Because `static` variables have to be initialized with a value known at compile-time, while `x` is only determined at run-time.

---

Note that this use of `static` is meant for to keeping the variable with its stored value between different calls to `foo()` alive (existing in memory) - Means the object won´t get destroyed/ deallocated after one single execution of the function, as it is the case with function-local variables of the storage class `auto`matic.

It wouldn´t make sense to create and initialize a `static` variable at each function call new.

Answer (score 0):

A variable declared with the static storage specifier have to be initialized with a constant value.

For example:

```
#define x 5
void foo()
{
    static int y = x;
}
```

OR

```
void foo()
{
    static int y = 5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to answer your question is to remind that you are using C, not C++. The same expression is fully valid in C++ where the initial value for a static variable may not be a constant.